# Asymptotic for the difference of binomial coefficents

Tags: combinatorics, limits, analysis, asymptotics, analytic-combinatorics

I have the following expression defined for all $n\geq 1$ and $k\geq 1$:

$$a_{n,k}=\frac{1}{n+1}
  \binom{2n}{n} - \binom{2n}{n} + \binom{2n}{n-1} + 
   \binom{2n}{n-k-1} - 2\binom{2n}{n-k-2} +
   \binom{2n}{n-k-3},$$

and I want to compute its asymptotic behavior (actually, the exponential growth would be enough) when $k=n^\alpha$ with $\alpha<1$, say $\alpha=0.99$.

I tried to plug in naively the asymptotic for binomial coefficients but I do not get anything meaningful. Any idea or help?

Comment: Have you tried Stirling's formula?

Comment: You should start by simplifying using $\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}n-\binom{2n}n+\binom{2n}{n-1}=0$, which can be proved with algebraic rearranging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using what @Mike Earnest wrote in comment, using the gamma function and simplifying
$$a_{n,k}= \binom{2n}{n-k-1} - 2\binom{2n}{n-k-2} +
   \binom{2n}{n-k-3}$$ $$a_{n,k}=2\, \Gamma (2 n+1)\,\frac{2 k^2+8 k+(7-n) } {\Gamma (n-k)\, \Gamma (n+k+4) }$$

Making $k=n^\alpha$ and expanding as Taylor series around $\alpha=1^-$, you could use

$$\Gamma \left(n-n^{\alpha }\right)=\frac{1}{(1-\alpha ) n \log (n)}+\left(\frac{1}{2 n}-\gamma
   \right)+O\left((\alpha -1)\right)$$
$$\Gamma \left(n+n^{\alpha }+4\right)=\Gamma (2 n+4)-(1-\alpha) n \log (n) \Gamma (2 n+4) \psi(2 n+4)+O\left((\alpha -1)^2\right)$$ which makes
$$\frac 1{\Gamma (n-k)\, \Gamma (n+k+4) }=\frac{ n \log (n)}{\Gamma (2 n+4)}(1-\alpha )+O\left((\alpha -1)\right)$$
$$2 k^2+8 k+(7-n)=\left(2 n^2+7 n+7\right)-4  n (n+2) \log (n)(1-\alpha )+O\left((\alpha -1)^2\right)$$ All of that gives
$$a_{n,k}=\frac{ n (2 n^2+7 n+7) \log (n)}{(n+1) (2 n+1) (2
   n+3)}(1-\alpha )+O\left((\alpha -1)^2\right)$$ .... which does not look fantastic.

Comment: Perhaps the question is about finding an asymptotic equivalence for $n \to \infty$, then we need to find the asymptotic behavior of $\exp((n \pm n^\alpha) \ln(n \pm n^\alpha))$. An expansion in terms of $\exp(c_i n^{p_i})$ will have $\lfloor 1/(1 - \alpha) \rfloor$ factors (some of which will cancel out).

Comment: @Maxim.I was wondering thé same. Why don't you put an answer ? Cheers

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I could derive an asymptotic formula.

Answer (score 3):

Assume that $k = n^\alpha$ with some $0\le\alpha<1$. I re-write Claude Leibovici's result in the form
$$
a_{n,k}  = \frac{{(2n)!}}{{(n - k)!(n + k - 1)!}}\frac{{2(n - k)(2(k + 2)^2 - n -1)}}{{(n + k)(n + k + 1)(n + k + 2)(n + k + 3)}}
$$
and focus on the asymptotics of the first factor. It may be shown, using the main result of [this paper](https://doi.org/10.7169/facm/1317045234), that
$$
\log (n + k - 1)! = \left( {n + k - \frac{1}{2}} \right)\log n - n + \frac{1}{2}\log (2\pi ) + \sum\limits_{j = 1}^{\left\lceil {\frac{\alpha }{{1 - \alpha }}} \right\rceil } {\frac{{( - 1)^{j + 1} B_{j + 1} (k)}}{{j(j + 1)}}\frac{1}{{n^j }}}  + o(1)
$$
and
$$
\log (n - k)! = \left( {n - k + \frac{1}{2}} \right)\log n - n + \frac{1}{2}\log (2\pi ) + \sum\limits_{j = 1}^{\left\lceil {\frac{\alpha }{{1 - \alpha }}} \right\rceil } {\frac{{( - 1)^{j + 1} B_{j + 1} (1 - k)}}{{j(j + 1)}}\frac{1}{{n^j }}}  + o(1),
$$
as $n\to+\infty$. Here $B_j(x)$ denotes the [Bernoulli polynomials](http://dlmf.nist.gov/24.2.E3). By [Stirling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation),
$$
\log (2n)! = \left( {2n + \frac{1}{2}} \right)\log (2n) - 2n + \frac{1}{2}\log (2\pi ) + o(1)
$$
as $n\to+\infty$. Accordingly,
$$
\frac{{(2n)!}}{{(n + k - 1)!(n - k)!}} = \sqrt {\frac{n}{{\pi }}} 4^n {\rm e}^{F(n,\alpha )} (1 + o(1))
$$
as $n\to+\infty$, with
$$
F(n,\alpha ) =  - \sum\limits_{j = 1}^{\frac{1}{2}\left\lceil {\frac{\alpha }{{1 - \alpha }}} \right\rceil } {\frac{{B_{2j} (k)}}{{j(2j - 1)}}\frac{1}{{n^{2j - 1} }}}  .
$$
In arriving at this form, I made use of the identity [$(24.4.3)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/24.4.E3).

Comment: Nice solution !